# URL Redirect - URL is appended to a new one instead of completely redirecting it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I have the following redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /TEST/ https://www.newdomain.com

Redirect 301 /somethingelse/mobile/ https://www.newdomain.com/somethingelse

Redirect 301 /MY-STUFF/my-portfolio/ https://www.newdomain.com/my-portfolio
```

The first one works, but the second and third one redirects to these wrong URLs:

```
https://www.newdomain.commobile/
https://www.newdomain.commy-portfolio/
```

Bur I'm expecting these redirections as a result:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/somethingelse
https://www.newdomain.com/my-portfolio
```

Can anyone please help? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` directive instead of `Redirect` to get a precise match:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/TEST/?$ https://www.newdomain.com

RedirectMatch 301 ^/somethingelse/mobile/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/somethingelse

RedirectMatch 301 ^/MY-STUFF/my-portfolio/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/my-portfolio
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or after clearing your browser cache.